# Given the current date, calculate the total sum for the past 12 months per customer (not rolling sum)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table with the following layout:

| Year | Month | Customer | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | January | Customer #1 | 1000 |
| 2021 | January | Customer #1 | 250 |
| 2021 | February | Customer #1 | 500 |
| 2021 | February | Customer #1 | 2500 |
| 2021 | March | Customer #1 | 300 |
| 2022 | January | Customer #2 | 200 |
| 2022 | February | Customer #1 | 200 |
| 2022 | March | Customer #1 | 500 |
| 2022 | March | Customer #2 | 1000 |
| 2022 | March | Customer #2 | 100 |

I am trying to calculate the past 12 month of sales per Customer given a current date.

At this moment I only know how to calculate the 12 trailing months. I came up with the first draft version of how I'd approach this:

```
SELECT Customer, Year, Month, SUM(Sales) as Total Sales per Customer INTO #temp
FROM Sales table
GROUP BY Customer, Year, Month
ORDER BY Year, Month
```

Once I get a table rolled up to Customer, Year, Month level I can apply the following:

```
SELECT SUM(Total Sales) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY Year Month ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW) AS Past 12 months Sales
FROM #temp
```

The output table will have the trailing 12 months. However, my goal is to get the current date with `GETDATE()`, look up the month and year in the table that corresponds to the current date, and calculate just the past 12 months from the current date.

I am figuring what SQL part I am missing to achieve my objective. I tried declare and set variables but they cannot be fed into the WHERE clause because the output is not value (like in Python).

Please advise on how to tackle this.

Comment: *but they cannot be fed into the WHERE clause* Not sure what you mean by that.  Could you post what you tried and any error messages?

Comment: I tired to include the GETDATE() outout to the WHERE clause. Just as an example: WHERE cast(concat(Year, ' ' , Month, ' 01') as Date) <= GETDATE() The fact that I add GETDATE() returns the error becasue that function does not return a value, it returns a cell with the value. Does it make sense?

Comment: use convert : `CONVERT(date,'31 december 2022',113)` returns date 2022-12-31, so in your case:  `where CONVERT(date,'01 ' + Month +' ' +CAST(Year as char(4)),113) > DATEADD(MONTH,-12,cast(GETDATE()-DAY(GETDATE()) as date))`

Comment: How to tackle? Design tables that facilitate querying. You made a huge mistake storing year and month separately. Another one is storing the month name. That complicates the logic of knowing which <year><month> follow another. Store a complete date (e.g., 20220101) and ignore the day part for most purposes.

Comment: @SMor yes, I agree, dates shouldn't stored like that, but this is what I have in the dataset.

Comment: @jjdesign I used the functions you have, it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `group by rollup()` you can have all in one:

```
set language english /*to make sure the sql session language you're running on is the same than the datas, otherwise CONVERT will not work*/

select  
    [Year]  = isnull(cast(Year as char(5)), 'total') 
   ,[Month] = isnull(Month, 'total')
   ,Customer
   ,[Sales] = SUM(sales)
from Sales
where 
   CONVERT(date,'01 ' + Month +' ' +CAST(Year as char(4)),113) > DATEADD(MONTH,-12,cast(GETDATE()-DAY(GETDATE()) as date))
group by ROLLUP((Year,Month))/*parenthesis means one unbreakable key*/,customer
order by customer, Year,Month
```

results:

```
2021    | March     | Customer #1   |  300
2022    | February  | Customer #1   |  200
2022    | March     | Customer #1   |  500
total   | total     | Customer #1   | 1000
2022    | January   | Customer #2   |  200
2022    | March     | Customer #2   | 1100
total   | total     | Customer #2   | 1300
```

Comment: With some modifications, I managed to get the sums. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the start date:

```
Declare @StartDate datetime = DATEADD(Month, -12, GETDATE())
```

Then add this where clause:

```
Where cast(Concat(Year, ' ', Month, ' 01') as Date) >= @StartDate
```

Comment: thank you! It pointed me in the right direction. I didn't use a variable though, was able to do it without it.

Comment: @Alice Please accept my answer if it solves your problem.